# Use key-value structure in relational database for store settings

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relational-database, liquibase

I have a `settings` table that stores some values.

```
CREATE TABLE `setting` (
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `p1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `p6` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p8` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `p9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p11` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p12` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p13` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p14` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p15` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `p16` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `p17` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
)
```

This `settings` table has just one row. Is better if I use `key-value` structure to store `settings` table values?
If I use `key-value` approach, I should convert `int` value to `String` and vice versa. 
I may alter table columns in the future.
Which approach has better maintenance?
which approach has better performance?
My application is written in `Spring Boot` and I use `Liquibase` for database migration.

Note: usage of this table's value is high in my application.

If `key-value` approach is better, Do you have any sample code for that?

Comment: One issue with KV approach is that you lose type info as the value column needs to be varchar and then you need to start converting stuff in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is debatable.

It depends on your attitude to data model. You can tighten up the screws, and make it as did in your question, or you can loosen it a bit and create key-value structure.

From what you've provided in your question, I'd go with key-value. It's easier to maintain a table with three columns, than with 18 columns. This way you can alter the table easily and you won't have to write and maintain the `Settings` entity with all these fields.

But sure, you'll have to keep in mind that in some cases values should (or should not) be null, and you'll have to convert String to Integer and vice-versa.

So nevertheless, your liquibase will be something like:

```
<changeSet id="foo1" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="settings"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Create settings table.</comment>
    <createTable tableName="settings">
        <column name="uuid" type="binary(16)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_settings"/>
        </column>
        <column name="key" type="varchar(3)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="value" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

    <changeSet id="foo2" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <and>
            <columnExists tableName="settings" columnName="uuid"/>
            <columnExists tableName="settings" columnName="key"/>
            <columnExists tableName="settings" columnName="value"/>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Fill settings table with data.</comment>
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO settings (uuid, key, value) VALUES (uuid(), 'p1', 'value-you-need');
        INSERT INTO settings (uuid, key, value) VALUES (uuid(), 'p2', 'value-you-need');

        <!-- ... etc ... -->

    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

And your entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings")
public class Settings {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    // getters and setters

}
```